# php exec crash with no output

Tags: php, process, exec

I need to check why my exec function stops my php script.

I call a bat file in "exec" function (but i have the problem to with passthru, system and proc_open) in my HTTP query and after 2min i got an error code 500 (with no details). But my bat file is always running in background (i can see files created...)
I use it like this :

```
exec('cmd /c myScript.bat "myParam" 2>&1 &', $output);
```

In $output i get nothing, in php error_log nothing... I've added this parameters :

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("track_errors", 1);
ini_set("html_errors", 1);
set_time_limit(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Same result...

I'm on PHP 7.2 and IIS 8.

Comment: The `2>&1` and `&` suffixes are less likely to work on Windows. You might have more luck with using Powershell as wrapper or instead of CMD there. Also test on the CLI first.  Check IIS's error.log (or use Apache;)

Comment: Thanks for your help. ;)

Comment: You can edit the answer if you want to show some more details (might benefit other/future users).

Answer (score 0):

OP found found a solution to the 2-minute-timeout issue:

- The problem was in config of IIS, in applicationHost.config.
- I have to change **activityTimeOut** in correct FastCgi.